# How to make two androidplot, each one take 50% of the screen?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, androidplot

I'm trying to make two `androidplot.xy.XYPlot` each one takes 50% of the screen. I try to use `android:weightSum`. I put each `androidplot.xy.XYPlot` inside an `LinearLayout`, each take half the weight but the plot is not showing.

Here is my XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#FF003B"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
                    android:id="@+id/pawGraph"
                    style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:rangeTitle="Pressure (cmH2O)"
                    app:graphMarginBottom="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#FFE600"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
                    android:id="@+id/tidalVolume"
                    style="@style/APDefacto.Light"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:graphMarginBottom="0dp"
                    app:lineLabelTextSizeBottom="0dp"
                    app:rangeTitle="Tidal Volume" />
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Android Studio Design View show the two layouts as I expected. Here is what Android Studio [Design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECDsa.png) looks like.

However, in my app both graphs does not [show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VguJv.jpg).

If I set `android:layout_height` within `com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot` to something like 250dp. Then [the graphs would show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDffQ.jpg). But now it is not 50% of the screen anymore.

What did I do wrong? How should I fix it?

Comment: Add `android:weightSum` property to child `LinearLayout` and `android:layout_weight` to `XYPlot` view.`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` may not work with some views inside parent layout.

Comment: @Harshali I tried that. It didn't work. I also try to completely remove the sub ```LinearLayout``` and just have 2 ```com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot``` inside 1 main ```LinearLayout```. That also didn't work

Comment: I also tried every combination of ```wrap_content```, ```match_parent```, ```0dp```. Nothing work

Comment: Have you checked how it looks in [layout inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) when you run it on the device?

Comment: @SergeiKozelko Here is my [component tree](https://imgur.com/a/Rd090xN) in Layout Inspector. I have no idea why the graphs do not show up here.

Answer (score 0):

> Please XY Plot to width and height both are set match parent so show this plot 50% of the screen.

Comment: Tried that but it [didn't work](https://imgur.com/a/isAoNRx).